# Using .class files in netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I'm trying to use a .class file I downloaded for a uni project. I don't have the .java file to go with it. I am using netbeans.

- I tried just adding it to the project src folder
- I tried using "add JAR/folder" on libraries and adding the directory containing it
- I also tried creating a JAR file of the directory containing it and adding that

Greatly appreciate any suggestions

Comment: How do you define "to use it"?

Comment: Nobody should provide a "library" as a .class file. A library should be provided as a jar file, along with documentation. With just a .class file, there is no way, without decompiling it, to know what package it belongs to, and thus where to put it in a project.

Comment: does your created jar have the correct package structure?

Comment: FatGiant - I want to create objects of the class

Comment: J Nizet - That is all we were given, could it be that it's package isn't defined?

Comment: It could. No way to know without documentation or the .class file. How do you intend to properly use the class if it's not documented and you don't have the source code? You'll try to guess what each method does based on its name? You'd better forget about it and use your own code.

Comment: Friwi - could you explain what you mean? sorry i am quite new to java

Comment: Download a java decompiler from the internet, decompile the class file into a java file and then add it to your project. Only way to use the file without guessing every method.

Answer (score 2):

You should do two things:

- Create a jar of the class file you received
- Create an overview which methods the classfile offers

For the latter you have at least two options. One is to use a decompiler (some authors of APIs deny you to use this) like [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui-download). The second options is to use [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), which comes with your JDK (I link to Java 8, but it exists in prior versions too). Simply call `javap yourfile.class` and you will see which method signatures the class offers.

But the easiest way to see the classes / methods inside the .class file is JD-GUI, so if you are not running into any legal issues use that approach.